# Partially failed insertion to related data

Tags: mysql, database

What should i do when i want to insert related data to different tables and one the insertions fail. So only a portion of the important related data is inserted to one of the tables. Then i obviously don't want that data fracture to stay in the table because it is not useful by itself. What are the best ways and technique to implement this kind of behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the best things that you can do is set the auto commit to 0.  From there you can nest it in a transaction.  **That way you can provide a conditional that if the table doesn't fully update, roll back and it is not saved to your disk.**

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT @A:=SUM(salary) FROM table1 WHERE type=1;
UPDATE table2 SET summary=@A WHERE type=1;
COMMIT;
```

I got this from the MYSQL website: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html

Comment: Can i make conclusions from a backend programming language regarding the outcome of a transaction, without checking the table with SELECT?

Comment: No you want to create a select statement that will get a value for your conditional, so then it will know to commit or rollback.

Answer (score 0):

This is what transactions are for.

A transaction wraps a bunch of transactions. At the end a transaction is either committed (all the changes made hit the disk) or rolled back (none of them are)

You start a transaction with the `BEGIN` statement, commit it with `COMMIT`, and roll it back with `ROLLBACK`